# Laravel 4.2: Eloquent is creating insert queries with NULL values

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

Mysql version is 5.6. community edition.
Laravel 4.2 Eloquent is creating insert queries with NULL values due to which I am getting the "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:" error.

Is there any way to make eloquent to replace the NULL values to empty strings?
or make laravel queries strict mode compliant?

I have already turned strict mode of for mysql and still getting the error.
I have also tried 'strict'=>true/false in the database config file but no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0):

For this, what I did was:

If the field has a default value of current_timestamp, i set the datatype to timestamp('field_name'), but if it doesnt have a current_timestamp default value, i set the datatype to dateTime and set it nullable().

```
//for timestamp
$table->timestamp('create_datetime')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

//for datetime
$table->dateTime('start_datetime')->nullable();
```

Hope it helps.